# TVAnimationsGestures reusable bug:

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, insert-update

I am using the sample template from apple which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/tableviewupdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_APLTableViewController_m.html). It works pretty well when there are only three sections. But if I multiply the number of sections by 5, and you open the section from the bottom most cell. Then scroll up and then scroll back down, You would see the cells are getting reused and the cell thinks that it is in the closed state causing a crash when you hit the section header of the cell that is opened.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Does anyone have a fix for the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle bug in the sample project.  The sample code does not account for APLSectionHeaderView objects being reused for other sections.

Add the line

```
sectionHeaderView.disclosureButton.selected = (section==self.openSectionIndex)?YES:NO;
```

just before returning from the method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and change this

```
        APLSectionInfo *previousOpenSection = (self.sectionInfoArray)[previousOpenSectionIndex];
        previousOpenSection.open = NO;
        [previousOpenSection.headerView toggleOpenWithUserAction:NO];
```

to this

```
        APLSectionInfo *previousOpenSection = (self.sectionInfoArray)[previousOpenSectionIndex];
        previousOpenSection.open = NO;
        if (previousOpenSection.headerView.section  == previousOpenSectionIndex) {
            [previousOpenSection.headerView toggleOpenWithUserAction:NO];
        }
```

in the method

```
- (void)sectionHeaderView:(APLSectionHeaderView *)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)sectionOpened
```